# How to restart R and continue a benchmark script from previous line (on Windows)?

Tags: r, profiling, benchmarking

I want to benchmark the time and profile memory used by several functions (regression with random effects and other analysis) applied to different dataset sizes.
My computer has 16GB RAM and I want to see how R behaves with large datasets and what is the limit.

In order to do it I was using a loop and the package *bench*.

After each iteration I clean the memory with gc(reset=TRUE).
But when the dataset is very large the garbage collector doesn't work properly, it just frees part of the memory.
At the end all the memory stays filled, and I need to restar my R session.

My full dataset is called allDT and I do something like this:

```
for (NN in (1:10)*100000)  {
    gc(reset=TRUE)  
    myDT <- allDT[sample(.N,NN)]
    assign(paste0("time",NN), mark( 
      model1 = glmer(Out~var1+var2+var3+(1|City/ID),data=myDT),
      model2 = glmer(Out~var1+var2+var3+(1|ID),data=myDT),
    iterations = 1, check=F))
}
```

That way I can get the results for each size.

The method is not fair because at the end the memory doesn't get properly cleaned.

I've thought an alternative is to restart the whole R program after every iteration (exit R and start it again, this is the only way I've found you can have the memory cleaned), loading again the data and continuing from the last step.

Is there any simple way to do it or any alternative?
Maybe I need to save the results on disk every time but it will be difficult to keep track of the last executed line, specially if R hangs.
I may need to create an external batch file and run a loop calling R at every iteration. Though I prefer to do it everything from R without any external scripting/batch.

Comment: Hi, it is not a direct answer to your question but maybe it will help you. You can use the function memory.limit() to get the available memory your pc have (RAM). You can also use the function memory.limit() to set up a part of the memory from the HDD this way : memory.limit(60000). So lets say you have 16GB RAM then R is gonna use 16GB RAM + 44GB of HDD space to execute your code. I was using this when R was crashing because a pc was lacking RAM. Maybe this would allow your R to not crash while the code is processing.

Comment: Hi. I'm already using the memory.limit function. Anyway when the dataset is large you don't have enough SSD disk.  I want to measure the timing and memory used for different dataset sizes.

Comment: Oh alright, it was working for me even when I use over 8-10GB data file. Also, yes I understand what you want to do, I just tough memory.limit() would allow your R not to crash. Someone better than me with R could probably help you with your question.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I do for benchmarks like this is to launch another instance of R and have that other R instance return the results to stdout (or simpler, just save it as a file).

Example:

```
times <- c()
for( i in 1:length(param) ) {
   system(sprintf("Rscript functions/mytest.r %s", param[i]))
   times[i] <- readRDS("/tmp/temp.rds")
}
```

In the `mytest.r` file read in parameters and save results to a file.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
NN <- args[1]
allDT <- readRDS("mydata.rds")
...
# save results
saveRDS(myresult, file="/tmp/temp.rds")
```